# Need to extract dynamic values from a string response in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I need to extract the dynamic value "`BSS1,DS1,HYS1,MS1,PTS1,QS1,USG1,YS1,RT10086,RT10081,RT10084,RT10082,OT10076,RT10083,UT10081,RT10085,`"
from the string response "`ACCOUNT_DETAIL_ACCOUNT_PRODUCT_SERVICES_EDIT_UPDATE_NameSpace.grid.setSelectedKeys(["BSS1","DS1","HYS1","MS1","PTS1","QS1","USG1","YS1","RT10086","RT10081","RT10084","RT10082","OT10076","RT10083","UT10081","RT10085"]);`"

I have tried using the regular expression extractor :

```
Regular Expression :Keys\(\[\"(.+?)\",\"(.+?)\",\"(.+?)\",\"(.+?)\",\"(.+?)\",\"(.+?)\",\"(.+?)\",\"(.+?)\",\"(.+?)\",\"(.+?)\",\"(.+?)\",\"(.+?)\",\"(.+?)\",\"(.+?)\",\"(.+?)\",\"(.+?)\"]\)

template : $1$$2$$3$$4$$5$$6$$7$$8$$9$$10$$11$$12$$13$$14$$15$$16$
```

But the above regular expression works only if there are 16 values in the response. If the response contains less number of values, for example, "`ACCOUNT_DETAIL_ACCOUNT_PRODUCT_SERVICES_EDIT_UPDATE_NameSpace.grid.setSelectedKeys(["BSS1","DS1"]);`"
 then the above regular expression doesn't work.

How can I extract the values in the response if the total count is unknown? 
Also the double quotes in the response need to be omitted.

Is there any post processor using which dynamic values can be extracted?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it will be easier with some scripting.

1. Add [Beanshell PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor) as a child of the request which returns aforementioned response
2. Put the following code into the PostProcessor's "Script" area:

   ```
   String response = new String(data);

   String rawKeys = response.substring(response.indexOf("[") + 1, response.indexOf("]")); // get the data inside square brackets
   String keysWithoutQuotes = rawKeys.replaceAll("\"", "");          // remove quotes
   String[] keyData = keysWithoutQuotes.split("\\,");                // get array of keys

   for (int i = 0; i < keyData.length; i++) {                       // store array of keys into JMeter variables like

     vars.put("Keys_" + (i +1), keyData[i]);                        // Keys_1=BSS1, Keys_2=DS1, etc.
   }

   vars.put("Keys_matchNr", String.valueOf(keyData.length));       // set Keys_matchNr variable
   ```

Where:

- `data` is byte array containing parent sampler's response data
- `vars` is a shorthand to [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class which provides read/write access to JMeter Variables.

As a result you'll have variables like:

```
Keys_1=BSS1
Keys_2=DS1
..
Keys_matchNr=X
```

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for additional information on Beanshell scripting in JMeter and some more examples